# exception when using application oracle forms

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

[image]Hello,
when 8 users use our application built with orcle forms 10g.
The application crashed for 4 users in the same interface.fmb and the others still work into the application.
The exception in this picture

Comment: I can't read the text in the image. Could you repost it zoomed in slightly so the text is clear please?

Comment: I change the resolution of image but you can zoom the image when you use the zoom of your browser please check it

Comment: Images are hard to read and not searchable, which lessens the utility of your post.  I know Java stacks are long and horrible, but the leat you could have done is write out the Oracle Forms error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
FRM-92100 An Unexpected Network error or server failure occurred.
```

It's a typically helpful Oracle error message 8-)

Basically, it's pretty generic, there's all sorts of things it could be.  If you have an Oracle Support Contract I suggest you surf over to MOS and read through the note on Troubleshooting FRM-92050 and FRM-921xx errors (note ID = 189867.1).

If you haven't got a support contract then I suggest you head for the OTN Forms forum and ask your question there.  Frankly Forms is now a niche tool and you've got a much better chance of getting helpful advice from a dedicated site with a community of specialists.    [Find them here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=82).

Comment: +1 for the Support note - that's an essential note when administrating an Oracle Forms application

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough guess from the security exception:

The exception would seem ti imply that either the server connection reset/closed, or there a limit on the number of concurrent connections allowed. Does the app run fine with 7 people, but once you get 8 in there, that's when it crashes?

Comment: There is not a limit of the number of user. the problem is there are some person still worked in th fmb and others use the fmb only when they start the application and then they could not access

Comment: Do you mean that, only 1 person can access a particular fmb at a time? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: some times 3 persons can access some times 4 the number of users who could acces is not fixed